# docker image testing: file not found

Tags: testing, docker

I made a docker image and was trying to test it. The image seems fine if I check the version of the application, but can't find the file if I give a legitimate command:

```
| => docker run -ti us.gcr.io/my_project/fastqc fastqc --version
```

FastQC v0.11.4

```
| => docker run -ti us.gcr.io/my_project/fastqc fastqc /Users/jedi/Documents/raw_data/Sample1_PE_R1.fastq.gz
```

Skipping '/Users/jedi/Documents/raw_data/Sample1_PE_R1.fastq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read

I tried putting the filepath in quotes, but got the same result. What am I doing wrong? How should I be testing a docker image?

thanks!

Comment: can you run `docker run -ti us.gcr.io/my_project/fastqc ls -l /Users/jedi/Documents/raw_data/Sample1_PE_R1.fastq.gz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a docker image and passing it a file that is in the host, not inside the docker container. This won't work.

In fact, host's and container's filesystems are separated (thats one of the cool things about docker).

If you want to run your command the way you are doing, you need to share a volume between your host and your docker container. Try running your command like this:

```
docker run -ti -v "/Users/jedi/Documents/raw_data/:/Users/jedi/Documents/raw_data/" us.gcr.io/my_project/fastqc fastqc "/Users/jedi/Documents/raw_data/Sample1_PE_R1.fastq.gz"
```

This way you are sharing the `/Users/jedi/Documents/raw_data/` folder between your host and your container, and the command should work.